# select JSON object depending value of an property

Tags: java, json

I have following code :

```
    try {
            List<Item> object = new ArrayList<Item>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setItemID(i);
                object.add(item);
                item=null;
            }           
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS);
            ObjectWriter ow = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

by `sysout` I got string in console like :

```
[ {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 0
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 1
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 2
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 3
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 4
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 5
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 6
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 7
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 8
}, {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 9
} ]
```

Now by generated text I want to search for an value of an property of each object.

For example:
I want to search for `itemID=6`, if found then that entire object need to be selected. So my result text will be

```
[ {
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "createdBy" : null,
  "dateModified" : null,
  "modifiedBy" : null,
  "itemID" : 6
} ]
```

I want solution in java not in Jquery or any client side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

"result" is a variable which contains your json.
Below code is written in java.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("array");
jArr.get(6);
```

jArr.get(6) will return the object at index 6.

And at specific value like this:

```
 JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("array");
   for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jobj1 = jArr.getJSONObject(i); 
       if(jobj1.getInt("itemID")==6){ 
        //Do your work } 
     }
```

Comment: OP said  `I want to search for a value of a property of each object.` What about if he wants to search by `createdBy`. Searching by index is not a solution, unless he only wants to search by id - which he doesn't.

Comment: @gudthing is saying correct. search by itemid is just an example. I can search by any property.

Comment: You can run a for loop to the size of the json and at each index you can match the item ID with your key. Like this

 JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("array");
  for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
   
   JSONObject jobj1 = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
   if(jobj1.getInt("itemID")==6){
    
    //Do your work
    
   }

Comment: @MarkHenry, Ohh this seems like looping on 'List<Item>' and checking for value of an property.

Comment: if the answer meet your requirements then up the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a List of `Item` objects. This `Item` has attributes like dateCreated, createdBy,...

Assuming that you have the getters for these attributes:

If you want to search for an attribute, you loop over the `List`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 if (list.get(i).getDateCreated().equals(_Date-you-are-looking-for)) {
  return list.get(i);
 }
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to search the JSON *string* that results, I would use regular expressions to capture the whole element you want:

`/\{.*?itemID=6.*?\}/`